# Count unique values within specified variable date range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm attempting to create a report that includes a count of unique values from a table. I'm using Excel 2010. Normally this would be an easy matter of adding a column to the source data with a formula to show "1" for the first instance of a unique value and "0" for any subsequent instances, the summing that column. For this I'm using `=IF(IF(COUNTIF($G$2:$G2,G2)>1,0,COUNTIF($G$2:$G2,G2))`.

I'm adding an additional wrinkle where the donor can select a date range using "StartDate" and "EndDate" fields I've created, and I'm trying to show the count within that range. This means the usual method won't work, as the first instance of the value may be cut-off in the date range selection, and subsequent instances that fall within the selection may show as "0" in the column.

So, how do I show a total count of unique values from a table, where the user can select their own date range, which will select the record's date field that they want to see (column C) and show the number of unique values (column G). I've tried using the "FREQUENCY" function but am having trouble building the formula to include the variable dates.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your formula like this: `=IF(COUNTIFS(G$2:G2,G2,C$2:C2,"<="&<max_date>,C$2:C2,">="&<min_date>)=1,1,0)`